# Coco2d v3 How to remove sprite from parent node like candy crush game?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

When I select the sprite type I want to remove the sprites from the node, Its only doing scale and its not removing from the node. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
for (ImageView *cookie in chain.cookies) {

        // 1
        if (cookie.sprites != nil) {

            // 2
            CCActionScaleTo *Scaleaction =[CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scale:0.1];
            CCActionCallBlock *action2=[CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

                [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
            }];


           // CCAction *scaleAction = [SKAction scaleTo:0.1 duration:0.3];
            //scaleAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
            [cookie.sprites runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[Scaleaction,action2]]];
            // 3
            cookie.sprites = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try with removeChild function.

Comment: try with [cookie.sprites removeFromParentAndCLeanup:YES] ... i think.

Comment: I have tried to removechild and also removefromparentcleanup , but it not working, still the images are there